# Shell command makefile parameter function

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile

Usually I run my code with a makefile this way:

```
CC = 'mpicc -D_MPI = 4' make cav2d2phase.tst
```

I run my code on 4 processors in parallel.

Now my main function contains parameters:

```
  int main (int argc, char * argv []) {

    if (argc> 1)
      Ra = atof (argv [1]);
    if (argc> 2)
      Pr = atof (argv [2]);

    size (npe ());
    origin (-0.5, -0.5);
    dimensions (ny = 1);
    DT = 0.1;
    TOLERANCE = 1e-6;
    N = 1 << MINLEVEL;
    // Ra = 1e5; Pr = 1 .;
    B = 1.2;
    run ();
  }
```

I don't know how to launch this code by assigning numeric values ​​to my variables Ra and Pr directly in the shell.

For example:

```
CC = 'mpicc -D_MPI = 4' make cav2d2phase.tst 2 Ra = 1e6
```

[My github with the makefiles](https://github.com/Suntoryy/Help)

Comment: Instead of linking a complicated set of makefiles it would be better to show a minimal `Makefile` that demonstrates your problem. It is difficult to understand what would happen when you enter the command from your example. Of course you can set environment variables like `Ra=1e6` for your `make` command and use these variables as command line arguments when you run your program from the makefile, e.g. `run_your_program $(Ra) $(Pr)`

Comment: If your `Makefile`s don't run your compiled program, it's not possible to change the values assigned to these variables because this would require running the resulting executable or modifying the code

Comment: Just a note, the code you’ve shown doesn’t run in POSIX-compatible shells due to the spaces around `=`.

Comment: Seems more conventional to write `CC=mpicc CFLAGS=-D_MPI=4 make cav2d2phase.tst`, or (in some settings, eg with an Automake generated Makefile `CC=mpicc CPPFLAGS=-D_MPI=4 ...`.  Putting CFLAGS in CC will undoubtedly break some builtin rules.

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear how the C code is invoked from inside your Makefile but you can pass on Make command line variables to your program.

Assume your application is invoked inside the Makefile as follows

```
cav2d2phase.tst: …
    ./your-program <$< >$@
```

Simply change that to

```
cav2d2phase.tst: …
    ./your-program ${Ra} ${Pr} <$< >$@
```

And invoke your make target:

```sh
CC='mpicc -D_MPI = 4' make cav2d2phase.tst 2 Ra=1e6
```